# How to access a variable from a method which was set in another method of the same module in elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I want to access argument x of m1 method from m2 method.

```
defmodule MyModule do

    def m1(x) do
        # some code
    end

    def m2() do
        # Accesss 'x' here
        IO.puts x
    end
end
```

How to access x from method m2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Hynek -Pichi- Vychodil

[ETS(Erlang Term Storage)](https://elixirschool.com/en/lessons/specifics/ets/) provides robust in memory store in the form of tables. Any data can be stored into the table using key value pair.
Here is my solution:

```
defmodule MyModule do

    def m1(x) do

        # Create named table and insert the variable

        :ets.new(:user_lookup, [:set, :protected, :named_table])
        :ets.insert(:user_lookup, {"key", x})

        # some code
    end

    def m2() do

        # Accesss 'x' here by using table lookup
        [{_, x}] = :ets.lookup(:user_lookup, "key")
        IO.puts x
    end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't do this. It is forbidden operation in BEAM so it is in Erlang and Elixir and all other BEAM based languages. It is the intended behavior you have to provide transparently all required input data for each function call. You can emulate it using other components of [Erlang Run-Time System (`erts`)](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/erts/users_guide.html). For example, you could use [`ets` (Erlang Term Storage)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/ets.html) or you could use process working as a server providing such storage. This constraint is a fundamental building block for making a highly reliable systems which is the primal purpose of Erlang. For more information read [Making reliable
distributed systems in the presence of software errors](http://erlang.org/download/armstrong_thesis_2003.pdf) thesis. It is described the best there at the beginning of work.

Answer (score 0):

No offense but based on your use case, it seems like you are thinking in OOP, in Elixir we don't really have the concept of "global variable", can you try something like this instead?

```
defmodule MyModule do

    def m1(x) do
        m2(x) # Call m2 with x
    end

    def m2(param) do
        IO.puts param
    end
end
```

Comment: I don't want to call m2 from m1. Method m2 will be called by some another module.